# Decrease the size of spectrogram created with seewave

Tags: r, graphics, size, spectrogram

I'm trying to visualize spectrographic representation of audio wave and export it into publication-quality format. It seems that the easiest way to do this with R is to use package [seewave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seewave/index.html). In the example below, I create 0.5 second white noise, generate `quartz()` window, and visualize white noise as `spectro`:

```
require(seewave)
n <- noisew(d=0.5, f=22050)
quartz(width=6, height=6)
spectro(n,f=22050)
```

Then I manually save the PDF, which creates 1.7MB file. It's very good quality, actually - too good. All those fine spectrographic color-pallet levels are drawn in vectors. Hence, if I embed it in LaTeX, it slows down everything horribly. If I open it in Illustrator and want to make some adjustments - it slows down everything horribly. But I can't make it into PNG or other bitmap format, because the quality will be too low, and I won't be able to make some finishing touches in Illustrator.

Any suggestions how can I decrease the size of this graphics, but still keep it vector?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think exporting it as a bitmap will make the quality too low? Did you know that you can export it with whatever resolution you want, using the `res=` option for the `png` device? A 300 or 600-ppi PNG is plenty high quality for print, and more than enough for most computer applications.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but I want to have a possibility to open this file in Adobe Illustrator to make some finishing touches, and for this I need a vector format.